# How to create a page reference in Wikipedia (synonym redirection)?

Tags: wikipedia

I want to internally add a reference to a wiki-page. For example, say the page name is The_Page_Name. I would like to add a known term (say, The_Reference) to Wikipedia that should redirect to The_Page_Name. They are both synonyms that overlap each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a "Redirect." Information on this can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Redirect

> To create a basic redirect manually, set `#REDIRECT [[target page name
>   here]]` as the only body text of the page. For instance, if you were
>   redirecting from "UK" to "United Kingdom", this would be the entire
>   body of the "UK" page:
>
> `#REDIRECT [[United Kingdom]]`